# Calculating Avg Burst size

Tags: mysql, time-series

Suppose we have table t with timestamp colmun ts, t is filled with data overtime.
It is reasonable to assume that data is inserted in bursts of n rows at intervals of few seconds between rows (not constant interval) and then not inserted for relatively long time. Im looking to find that n. Any suggestion?

Im using MySQL so MySQL code sample would be great, but also suggestions of known algorithm to use or whatever can be good as well...

Comment: Please share the table and data with us and also provide us with the expected results.. you wil get more and maybe better answers

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, it sounds like a problem I've had to solve before too.  (Although it was disguised for me.)

MySQL doesn't have a way to efficiently see the difference between previous/next records.  I worked around this by introducing a linked list to the table.

The cost of doing this was all inserts and deletions had to go through a transactionally safe procedure which kept the (double-)linked list in tact.  I opted for a pair of stored procedures, which worked beautifully.

Resulting datasets looked like this:

```
+------------------------------------+
| id | insert_ts | prev_id | next_id |
+------------------------------------+
| 1  | 12:32     | NULL    | 2       |
| 2  | 12:34     | 1       | 3       |
| 3  | 12:40     | 2       | NULL    |
+------------------------------------+
```

(Indexed uniquely with a foreign key to itself on `prev_id` and `next_id`.)

Querying then the gap between any record and what preceded it is simply:

```
SELECT 
  my.id,
  my.insert_ts - prev.insert_ts
FROM table AS my
LEFT JOIN table AS prev ON (my.prev_id = prev.id)
```

Make sure if you're using date/timestamps you use the appropriate time comparison function and not the mathematical 'minus' as I did above.

To assure you on performance - this was a moderately high-throughput table on a financial system, data consistency was rock solid and throughput never bottlenecked.  I can provide you some hints on how to implement the routines to insert/delete.

Comment: Nice linked list implementation, but what about calculating the burst size n? how would you suggest on doing that?

Comment: I'm possibly not understanding your original question, I thought the example `SELECT` query in my answer demonstrated how to?  Am I correct in understanding that `n` is the time *between* any two records being inserted?

Comment: If you're looking to see how many records were inserted ever 10 seconds (as a period of time from timestamp A to B) with a count of records, the most optimal method would be to iteratively plot that data in a stored procedure (or language of your choice).  SQL can only group by data it has available to it (in a table).

Comment: If you understand this problem correctly (and I'm not saying you don't), then your skill set is verging on psychic.